# Understanding an apparently incorrect definition in Shelah's text on $\lambda$-frames

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $n$ be a Von Nemuan natural number, i.e. the set of all natural numbers less then $n$.
Why it holds that $\mathscr{P}^-(n)\overset{def}{=}\{u:u\subseteq \{0,...,n-1\}\}$
$=\mathscr{P}(n)\setminus \{n\}$?

Here in 12.19(3) is the [source](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/705/).
The author has $\in$ instead of my $\subseteq$, but I think, that in any case the second equality is *wrong*. Am I right? What he intends to define as $\mathscr{P}^-(n)$ and why he derives an incorrect conclusion that it equals $\mathscr{P}(n)\setminus \{n\}$? Here $\mathscr{P}(n)$ is the powerset of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

See : - Saharon Shelah, [Classification Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=5pwf8DGNHckC&pg=PA598) (revised ed - 1990), page 598 :

> *Notation 2.2*. $\mathscr{P}^-(s) = \{ t : t \subseteq s, t \ne s \}$

i.e. $\mathscr{P}^-(s) = \mathscr{P} \setminus \{ s \}$.

Thus, it seems that there is a typo; it should be :

> $\mathscr{P}^-(n) \overset{def}{=} \{ u : u\subseteq n= \{ 0,...,n-1 \}, u \ne n \} = \mathscr{P}(n) \setminus \{n\}$.

But we can equally write :

> > $\mathscr{P}^-(n) \overset{def}{=} \{ u : u\subset n= \{ 0,...,n-1 \} \} = \mathscr{P}(n) \setminus \{n\}$.

Comment: Ah. in the "$\subsetneq$" sense, yes.

Comment: Thank you,Maura, you've proved false all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Shelah's paper, in 12.10 (p.188) he defines $$\mathscr{P}^-(u_*) = \{v \subseteq u_* \mid v \neq u_*\}$$
So $\mathscr{P}^-(n)$ *is* equal to $\mathscr{P}(n)\!\setminus\! \{n\}$.

The chain of equalities you quote is on p.201. The *first* equality is suspect: whether with "$\in$" as he has it or "$\subseteq$" as you have it, neither works.

Comment: +1: Good catch! So, it looks like $\mathscr{P}^-(X)$ is intended to be the set of proper subsets of $X.$ So, that first equality fails to hold unless $n\le1$ as Shelah put it, and fails to hold unless $n=1$ as the OP put it.

Comment: @CameronBuie And good of you to notice that at least it holds *somewhere* :)

Comment: Shelah is a genius who is also known for his killer typos.

Comment: But he never makes a serious mistake which would render some of his results false.He is well aware what is true and what is not.

Comment: I certainly noticed, but wrongly so. The OP's version actually never holds. Oops!

Comment: @CameronBuie You're forgiven. I checked Shelah's with $n\le 1$, that panned out, looked at OP's, and said "whatever, it's broken anyway" :)